# Tool to publish static website using FTP

Tags: windows, command-line, ftp

### Purpose

To publish changes to a static website from a local Windows-10 PC to a remote webserver using FTP.

In the past I have used various tools (CuteFTP, FileZilla). Currently I just drag and drop using two Windows-Explorer windows (one opening an ftp://user@server/dir/ target). This requires me to manually select the files changed since the last update.

In the distant past I used DreamWeaver, which would automatically select files that had changed.

I can't use SSH, SCP, Rsync etc as the shared server is managed by a hosting service which only offers FTP uploads. In some cases I have no say over choice of hosting provider.

### Objective Requirements

#### Essential

- Command line tool.
- FTP client.
- Able to publish multiple files and subdirectories in one command.
- Works out which files need publishing
- Binaries for Windows-10

Everything beyond here is icing on the cake and nonessential.

#### Preferable

- Open source, Free.
- Options for previewing list of files to be published.
- Options for asking for file by file Y/N confirmation
- Some way of specifying folders or file patterns to include or exclude

#### Desirable to prevent temporary glitching in service

- uploads all CSS, JPG, PDF before any HTML/SHTML
- uploads using a prefix or suffix and renames when upload complete.

Comment: Not tried, hence just a comment: [FTPSync](http://www.cyberkiko.com/page/ftpsync/). Also, [WinSCP does offer that feature](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_synchronize) (yes, via FTP). Other possible candidates can be found [searching for `ftpsync windows`](https://www.google.com/search?q=ftpsync+windows) :)